# Swagger API definition load API definition - Cant use schema id "$Module"

Tags: .net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I am getting this exception when I want to create a Domain object with name `Module`

```
InvalidOperationException: Can't use schemaId "$Module" for type "$Pro.Core.Domain.Module". The same schemaId is already used for type "$System.Reflection.Module"
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SchemaRepository.RegisterType(Type type, string schemaId)
```

Seems like this name Module is conflicting with some `System.Reflection.Module`.

I have searched the internet and I have below 2 solutions that can get this working:

1. Rename my Module class name to something else but not Module(lets say MyModule)
2. Doing something like below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddSwaggerGen(config =>
 {
     //some swagger configuration code.

     //use fully qualified object names
     config.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName);
 }
}
```

But I want to understand that what is there in name `Module` that creates this error. I don't see any reason for not being allowed to use this name as my domain class name.

Is there any way to use the Domain Object with name `Module` other that mentioned above in point 2 and why is this happening in the first place?

Comment: I have tried but still not able to know the reason of this. IF SOMEONE CAN HELP IT WOULD BE GREAT. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.ToString());
});
```

Find more details from
[here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1607)